# Print the files if exists from different folders with same suffix integer value in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, bash-scripting

I have two different folders

```
Folder1                       Folder2
cmp_data_0.bin                decmp_data_0.bin
cmp_data_1.bin                decmp_data_1.bin
cmp_data_89.bin               decmp_data_78.bin
```

My shell script iterates through files in folder1 .
I would like to know if corresponding file in folder2 with same suffix integer value exists i.e ( comp_data_0.bin, decmp_data_0.bin ) , ( cmp_data_1.bin, decmp_data_1.bin) .

```
 for file in Folder1/*;
    do
      for file1 in Folder2/*;
      do
      ?? How to check for corresponding file with same suffix value as $file
    done
done
```

I need to process file and file 1 later after obtaining the matching files with same suffix integer value.

Comment: Is `decmp_data_` fixed and known in advance? Is `.bin` fixed? In other words: should or shouldn't `*0*` be the right globbing pattern to find a file corresponding to `cmp_data_0.bin`? I guess not, since it matches `decmp_data_10.bin`. So maybe `*_0.*`? or `*_0.bin`? or *strictly* `decmp_data_0.bin`? In yet other words: should `unrelated-0.txt` be considered a file corresponding to `cmp_data_0.bin`?

Comment: Hi.. The filenames without the suffix are fixed AND always be decmp_data_x.bin, cmp_data_x.bin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to iterate over files in `Folder2`. For every file in `Folder1` rebuild (translate) its pathname to the pathname of expected corresponding file in `Folder2`. Then check if such file exists.

```
#!/bin/sh

prefix1=Folder1/cmp_data_
suffix1=.bin
prefix2=Folder2/decmp_data_
suffix2=.bin

for f in "$prefix1"*"$suffix1"; do
   g="${f#"$prefix1"}"
   g="${g%"$suffix1"}"
   g="$prefix2$g$suffix2"
   if [ -e "$g" ]; then
      printf '%s\t->\t%s\n' "$f" "$g"
   else
      printf '%s\t--\t%s\n' "$f" "NO MATCH"
   fi
done
```

Notes:

- The code does not check if the part matched by `*` is all digits.
- The shebang `#!/bin/sh` means the code is portable. You tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash). The code will work in Bash as well.
- I used tab characters in the output, so you can improve the visual layout by piping to `column -ts $'\t'`. This will work in Bash; it may not work in `sh` because `$'\t'` is not portable. More portable syntax is `column -ts "$(printf '\t')"`, but `column` itself is not portable (i.e. not specified by POSIX) in the first place.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1631855/split-a-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-values-from-bookkeeper-file.. Can you check this one too ??