# Split a file into multiple files based on values from bookkeeper file

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting

I have 2 files, where I need to split File 1 into multiple files of size specified by File 2 contents. Sum of File 2 contents will always be equal to size of file 1. There can be many entries in File 2.

```
File 1 - Size 100 bytes

Ex: File 2 with content
10 - Split first 10 bytes of file to file1_1
10 - Split second 10 bytes of file to file1_2
80 - Split last 80 bytes of file to file1_3

20- Split first 20 bytes of file to file1_1
50- Split the file1 with 50 bytes after first split
30-Last 30 bytes of file 1 to file1_3..
```

Comment: ok. its trivial is most programming languages. Poking around bash doesn't do binary reads easily (though apparently possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889659/read-a-file-by-bytes-in-bash), so I'd probably look at Python or Perl, or C.

Comment: I think it is possible with DD tool, but I am stuck with it how to implement

Comment: DD is not a file level tool. yeah you can probably hack it, but why try? DD is dangerous if used improperly. Its looking like there are some options with hex conversion. check out xxd https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/xxd.1.html . you could read the file as a hex dump, and cut up the bytes from there, writing them back to binary.

Comment: I am fine with any solution in Shell Script..

Comment: It is possible with `dd`. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278465/108618). Extracting numbers from the other file and putting things together is another story. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Questions should show reasonable research effort. Are you familiar with the `read` builtin?